# Can't upload .htaccess after editing in notepad

Tags: htaccess

Switching site from http to https, but in `.htaccess` I can't upload file successfully after adding

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

in the file using notepad to enforce secure page. Format is UTF-8.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean you can't upload it?  Please explain what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> using notepad to enforce secure page. Format is UTF-8.

The problem is that Windows Notepad saves UTF-8 files with a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) - which it uses to identify the file encoding (other systems, Apache included, do not require this). If you look at the saved file in a hex editor, you will see the 3 bytes `EF BB BF` (that displays as `ï»¿` in CP1252) at the start of the file.

It is likely that this BOM is breaking Apache. (I would perhaps expect you are seeing a 500 Internal Server Error response?)

If using Notepad, save as "ANSI" (for simple files like this), or use a different editor.

Comment: I use Notepad++ for simple jobs like this you can find at https://notepad-plus-plus.org/.  Mainly for WordPress, I use PHPStorme from Jetbrains. https://jetbrains.com